# Adding a view above a navigation bar

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, ios7

I'm trying to achieve an effect similar to that seen in the new Messages app (Safari, too) on iOS 7, whereby there is a progress bar within the navigation bar itself:

[image: Progress bar as seen within the navigation bar in iOS 7]

I've tried a few approaches, and found one that almost works. I'm using is a custom subclass of `UINavigationBar` that adds my custom progress bar as a subview at initialisation time. This works almost fine, but the app crashes when I try to add `NSLayoutConstraints` to it.

**Working code (without layout constraints, so therefore doesn't adjust to orientation changes):**

```
- (void)commonInit
{
    if (!self.progressIndicator) {
        self.progressIndicator = [[ECourseProgressIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.bounds.size.height - 3, self.bounds.size.width, 3)];
        [self addSubview:self.progressIndicator];
    }
}
```

**Code I would expect to be able to use (with `NSLayoutConstraint`s added), but crashes:**

```
- (void)commonInit
{
    if (!self.progressIndicator) {
        self.progressIndicator = [[ECourseProgressIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.bounds.size.height - 3, self.bounds.size.width, 3)];
        [self addSubview:self.progressIndicator];

        self.progressIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-0-[progressIndicator]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"progressIndicator": self.progressIndicator}]];
        [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[progressIndicator(==3)]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"progressIndicator": self.progressIndicator}]];
    }
}
```

The error that I experience when running the code with the layout constraints is included in a Gist [here](https://gist.github.com/obeattie/6c71a04d2704a0692608#file-gistfile3-txt). If I don't set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO`, then the code works, but the layout constraints I specified are ignored in favour of the autoresizing mask constraints.

Can anyone shed any light?

P.S. I did initially think of adding the progress bar as a view above the UINavigationBar (so not in its hierarchy at all), but I can find no information of how to position a view visually above the navigation bar (in Z co-ordinate terms, not Y).

*Note: I [posted this](https://devforums.apple.com/message/877088#877088) in the Apple developer forums, but got no reply.*

Comment: What does the crash log say? It's usually helpful telling you what's wrong. Also, rather than subclass the Nav bar, why not just add the progress indicator as a subview of the navigation bar?

Comment: @Abizern I included it in a Gist with it inline as I didn't want to overwhelm the thread with it: https://gist.github.com/obeattie/6c71a04d2704a0692608#file-gistfile3-txt

Comment: In your ECCourseIndicatorProgressView, you don't happen to return `YES` for `+requiresConstraintBasedLayout` do you?

Comment: @Abizern I haven't defined that method. Should I?

Comment: @Abizern I just added the code for `ECourseProgressIndicatorView` to the Gist here: https://gist.github.com/obeattie/6c71a04d2704a0692608#file-gistfile4-m

Comment: Not unless you want to force auto layout. And also - you're setting the frame of your progress bar. Naughty, naughty, You don't want to touch frames when you are using auto layout, that's what the constraints are supposed to do. use `CGRectZero` as the frame in the initialiser.

Comment: @Abizern Sadly changing that results in the same error (`Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. EProgressIndicatingNavigationBar's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.`)

Comment: The assertion is in `EProgressIndicatingNavigationBar` which you haven't shown any code for.

Comment: The code in the question itself was from that class, but I've put the full code here: https://gist.github.com/obeattie/6c71a04d2704a0692608#file-gistfile5-m

Answer (score 5):

The trick is to add a view to the titleView of navigationItem. Set that view's cliptobounds to NO, and add the progress view inside that.

```
UIView *test = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 128, 33)];
[test setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[test setClipsToBounds:NO];


// Add the progress view
UIProgressView *progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleBar];
[progressView setFrame:CGRectMake(-96, 36, 320, 2)];
[progressView setProgress:1.0];
[progressView setProgressTintColor:SYSTEM_BLUE];


[test addSubview:progressView];

self.navigationItem.titleView=test;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put this view into the NavigationController, not the NavigarionBar.

Answer (score 0):

you can set Titleview for your navigation bar...just set any UIView as navigation bar titleview..then you can set any subview on that UIView..

```
UIView *viewBar=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 800, 44)];
UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 0, 50, 50)];
[label setText:@"Sending"];
[viewBar addSubview:label];
self.navigationItem.titleView=viewBar;
```

Happy Coding....